# Selected Item in combobox to datagrid C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, combobox

We have a combo box with different music genres. We want the selected genre, in the combo box, to show the songs in the database, of that genre, and then display it in the datagrid.

```
public DataSet sortGenreCBox()
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand genreBox = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct Genre From Sang", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(genreBox);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```

The code shows how we are extracting the genres from our database.

```
public ChooseSong()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _DBF = new DatabaseFacade();

        DataSet dsGenreBox = _DBF.sortGenreCBox();
        DataTable dtGenreBox = dsGenreBox.Tables[0];
        sortByGenreCBox.DataContext = dtGenreBox;
        sortByGenreCBox.DisplayMemberPath = dtGenreBox.Columns[0].ToString();

      ...
    }
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: And what is the Problem?

Comment: We want the selected genre in the combo box, to show the songs in the database, of that genre, and then display it in the datagrid.
But we don't know how? that is our problem :-)

Comment: are you following MVVM or just getting data in the code behind?

Comment: Sorry we don't know what MVVM is? Can you be more specific :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the gerne from the combo box and put that gerne in the SQL Query.

Create the query like:

```
 SqlCommand genreBox = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " + sortByGenreCBox.selectedItem  + " FROM Sang", conn);
```

And set the datagridview.DataSource to the DataSet ds.

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```

EDIT:

You can do something like:

```
public ChooseSong()
{
   string selectedGerne = sortByGerneCBox.selectedItem.text;
   DataSet ds = DatasortGenreCBox(selectedGerne);
```

Then you can do:

```
       public DataSet sortGenreCBox(string selectedGenre){
 SqlCommand genreBox = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " + selectedGenre  + " FROM Sang", conn);
}
```

Comment: We are unabled to type .text after 'string selectedGenre = sortByGenreCBox.selectedItem'

Comment: Sorry you need to do .toString().

Comment: But these things are all basic stuff, maybe you need to do more research on the problems you have. It's all already answered somewhere. Goodluck. P.S. Please mark as answer

Comment: What do you mean by 'DatasortGenreCBox' ?
I will mark as answer if you help a little bit more :p

Comment: That is your own created name for your comboBox?

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataSet sortGenreCBox()
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand genreBox = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct" + sortByGenreCBox.SelectedItem + "from Sang", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(genreBox);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```

When we write it in, it says that it doesn't exist in the current content?

Comment: what you have written there will only return the genre, you need to use a full SQL statement 'Select stuff From place WHERE something to limit by'